# Webpack4 with sass-loader, MiniCssExtractPlugin and uikit

Tags: sass, uikit, webpack-4, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I´m trying to setup a uitkit template with

- webpack 4
- sass loader
- MiniCssExtractPlugin
- uikit

What I would like to achieve is that a build automatically converts sass to css and that resulting css is injected into src/index.html.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          importLoader: 4
        }
      },
      "sass-loader"
    ]}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

**index.js**

```
import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';
import style from "uikit/src/scss/uikit.scss"
UIkit.use(Icons);
```

**Unfortunately a build fails with**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/uikit/src/scss/uikit.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/uikit/src/scss/uikit.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
$inverse-base-color: $inverse-global-color !default;
Undefined variable: "$inverse-global-color".
in new_proj/node_modules/uikit/src/scss/components/base.scss (line 607, column 49)
```

I would be thankful if one could explain What I´m doing wrong and why sass loader cannot find the variable $inverse-global-color.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the answer. It´s working like this:

index.js

```
...
import style from "./main.scss"
...
```

main.scss

```
// 1. Your custom variables and variable overwrites.
$global-link-color: #DA7D02;

// 2. Import default variables and available mixins.
@import "uikit/src/scss/variables-theme.scss";
@import "uikit/src/scss/mixins-theme.scss";

// 3. Your custom mixin overwrites.
@mixin hook-card() { color: #000; }

// 4. Import UIkit.
@import "uikit/src/scss/uikit-theme.scss";
```